# How can I pass all wifi traffic through Tor?

Tags: linux, transparent-proxy

Background:
Where I work there is a transparent proxy which restricts us to connect only to ftp, http and https websites.

I am using Tor and to connect to any other destination port I use proxychains on my Ubuntu machine, things work fine.

Problem:
Now I created a hotspot on my linux machine and want all incoming wifi traffic to be redirected through Tor. (Basically I have a ssh/telnet client on my Ipad which I want to use.)

How can I do this? Is it possible to setup some proxy server on my laptop so it redirects all(ALL TCP traffic) traffic through Tor?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324685/how-to-route-all-internet-traffic-through-tor-the-onion-router

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a good idea, in theory at least. (False security as programs may leak data)

Adafruit offers a [tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) on how to do this using a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian (which is based on Debian). This should work fine on most Linux distros.

> ```
>  sudo apt-get install tor
> ```
>
> [image: screenshot of terminal install of Tor]
>    Edit the tor config file by running
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/tor/torrc
> ```
>
> and copy and paste the text into the top of the file, right below the
>   the FAQ notice.
>
> ```
> Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log 
> VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10 
> AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit 
> AutomapHostsOnResolve 1 
> TransPort 9040 
> TransListenAddress 192.168.42.1 
> DNSPort 53
> DNSListenAddress 192.168.42.1
> ```
>
> [image: screenshot of terminal editing torrc]
>   Let's edit the host access point so it is called something memorable like Onion Pi - don't forget to set a good
>   password, don't use the default here! (Don't forget to do the AP setup
>   step in "Preparation" before this!) 
>   [image: screenshot of editing Wifi settings]
>
> [EDIT BY ANSWER AUTHOR]
>
> You can do this by editing /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf to change the ssid.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
> ```
>
> One might change it to:
>
> ```
> ssid=Onion Pi
> ```
>
> [END EDIT]
>
> Time to change our ip routing tables so that connections via the wifi
>   interface (wlan0) will be routed through the tor software. Type the
>   following to flush the old rules from the ip NAT table
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -F
> sudo iptables -t nat -F
> ```
>
> If you want to be able to ssh to your Pi after this, you'll need to
>   add an exception for port 22 like this (not shown in the screenshot
>   below)
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
> ```
>
> Type the following to route all DNS (UDP port 53) from interface wlan0
>   to internal port 53 (DNSPort in our torrc)
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
> ```
>
> Type the following to route all TCP traffic from interface wlan0 to
>   port 9040 (TransPort in our torrc)
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
> ```
>
> Next you can check that the ip tables are right with
>
> ```
> sudo iptables -t nat -L
> ```
>
> [image: screenshot of terminal of above command]
>
> If all is good, we'll save it to our old NAT
>   save file
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
> ```
>
> It will automatically get loaded when the networking is set up on
>   reboot (as we did in the last tutorial on making a Pi access point)
>   [image: screenshot of terminal after restart] Next we'll create our log file (handy for
>   debugging) with
>
> ```
> sudo touch /var/log/tor/notices.log
> sudo chown debian-tor /var/log/tor/notices.log
> sudo chmod 644 /var/log/tor/notices.log
> ```
>
> Check it with
>
> ```
> ls -l /var/log/tor
> ```
>
> Start the tor service manually
>
> ```
> sudo service tor start
> ```
>
> Check its really running (you can run this whenever you're not sure,
>   it something is wrong you'll see a big FAIL notice
>
> ```
> sudo service tor status
> ```
>
> Finally, make it start on boot
>
> ```
> sudo update-rc.d tor enable
> ```
>
> [image: screenshot of terminal after above command]
>   That's it, now you're ready to test in the next step.
>
> ([Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/install-tor))

Edit: Please look at [Tails](https://tails.boum.org) which does the same thing with much less risk.

Comment: With a few necessary modifications this worked :)
Important issue I found was with hostapd in 14.04. So manually installed from 13.10 repo.

Comment: @Swapniel It was a long shot, but it's good that it worked.

Comment: Hi unfortunately the iptables don't work for me. I first used ````sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT```` where I got a successful AP running. When I change it to your iptables, the AP doesn't have a connection anymore. Any ideas how to debug it to find out what is going wrong? Thanks!